# Is rolling to escape a monster required?

Tags: munchkin

In some cases, the Bad Stuff of a monster may actually be beneficial, for instance dying to draw new cards, if you were dealt bad cards at the start.

But is rolling required to let the monster take you, or can you simply "lie down at the ground" and let the monster kill you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No you can't choose to take the Bad Stuff, you must always attempt to Run Away first.

From the [Munchkin rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/munchkin_rules.pdf) (page 3 under **Combat**):

> If the monster’s combat strength is equal to yours,
>   or greater, you **lose the combat** and must Run Away

Also from page 5 under **Running Away**:

> If nobody will help you . . . or if somebody tries to help, and your fellow
>   party members interfere so the two of you still cannot win . . . you must Run
>   Away.

Note that in both cases they use the word **must** - you do not have the choice to run away (or not) - you must make the Run Away check, and must include all bonuses from active Races/Classes etc.

However you could still play one shot cards against yourself to change the possible outcome eg. a loaded die to change the die result to a 1, or a lose your class card to remove a class that gives you a bonus to running away.